# Mongoose schema does not work for Mongo Atlas

Tags: node.js, mongoose, mongodb-atlas

I am migrating the MongoDB database which is running on my local machine to MongoDB Atlas(a copy of the local DB). I have created a middleware using NodeJS and ExpressJS to get the records from the MongoDB.
To access the MongoDB from my Node application, I am making use of Mongoose. I have defined a schema for the collection.
When I am connecting to the local copy of the MongoDB, all the endpoints work correctly and I get the required results. But as soon as I try to access the DB hosted on Atlas, I do not get any results while using mongoose and the same schema. When I try to retrieve the data using mongodb driver and MongoClient, I get the data but not while using mongoose.
Any idea as to why this might be happening? I have checked the permissions of users and it is correctly configured.

Thanks!

index.js:

```
const url = "mongodb+srv://<username>:<password>@mumbaicluster.4yone.gcp.mongodb.net/<db>?retryWrites=true";
const connect = mongoose.connect(url,{useUnifiedTopology: true, useNewUrlParser: true, useCreateIndex: true})

var app = express()
app.use(cors())
const connection = mongoose.connection;
    connection.once('open',() => {
    console.log("Connected!")
    app.use("/",productRouter)
})
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}))
```

Removed username, password and DB name.

router.js:

```
productRouter.route("/").get((req, res, next) => {
  Product.find({}).then((products) => {
    res.statusCode = 200;
    res.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
    res.send(products);
  });
});
```

I can access the DB using MongoDB Compass

Comment: Can you share mongoose code snippet ?

Comment: including the connection url

Comment: what is the the response from remote db, is connection not created, collection not found or empty record ?

Comment: It is returning an empty array when I use find to retrieve all records